# Saving text from text field Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

And he's back with another n00bic question.

Hi all,
I am having difficulties in saving text from text field to a string.
I wrote this method:

```
-(IBAction)saveTextForSharing:(id)sender{

    NSString *textForSharing = [TextForSharing text];
}
```

Now there's a semantic issue- Unused variable 'textForSharing'.
Another method I wrote is that one:

```
- (IBAction)shareOnTumblr:(id)sender{
    NSString *someText = *textForSharing;
}
```

and there's that error:

Semantic Issue: Initializing 'NSString *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'UITextField'.
Can someone help?
(And bring me a good guide for n00b from C to Objective C and iOS Development so I won't trouble you answering my questions?)

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have compiled the project and I am having this error- Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

plus I want to notify the user about what he's going to post. I tried this-

```
NSString *someText = textForSharing;
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:(@"Are you sure you want to post %@ on your facebook wall?", *someText) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

But it gives me- error:Experession result unused and error: Sending 'NSString' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSString *'
What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `NSString` member `textForSharing` as class member variable (declare it in .h file).
Here in your case, it is temp variable.

Also , in share method, make the line as follows,

```
NSString *someText = textForSharing;
```

Comment: +1, I might also suggest that you check out the first part of this video regarding variable scope: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7Z56aRpSe8

Answer (score 0):

**First** one is warning because local variable `textForSharing` is not being used in the function.

For **second** error, you statement should be as below.

```
NSString *someText = textForSharing;
```

Suggest you to declare `textForSharing` as your class variable.

Comment: Thanks for the first one. The second also helped.